# htaccess 301 redirect sub directory to main domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

example.com the main blog and example.com/community is vanilla forums. 
The /community has its own posts and links.

I am removing /community directory and shutting down the forums.
The problem is that when anyone from google or some other user might open /community links it would show 404 error.

So I want example.com/community including all the links inside /community
for example example.com/community/mypost.html  to redirect to example.com with is the main domain.